# atomic model save in django

Tags: django, atomic

I've three models Question, Submission, UserResult. users submit an answer to a Question, this answer is scored by the system and stored in a Submission.

The score of a user for one question is maximum amongst all of his/her submissions. This score is saved in a model called UserResult(it has three fields, a foreign key to Question, another to User and a score which is an integer)

What I want to do is to make sure when a submission is saved the related UserResult is updated. Actually it's better not to store a submission when the result is not updated. So the submission should be saved only if UserResult is updated correctly. So this whole process should be atomic. What is the proper way of handling this?

Comment: posting code would make it easier on us

Comment: I haven't still coded this. I want to know what to do before starting to code

Comment: In submission save, call UserResult update method, and mark save method as `@transaction.atomic`.

Comment: You can override ```Submission.save(...)``` method or using ```@post_save``` signal. After saving ```Submission``` you can check if there is a proper ```UserResult``` record. If it isn't — you delete ```Submission```.

Comment: @Gocht: Can I use signals as well? (if i mark save with transaction.atomic will it work on pre/post save signals too?)

Comment: @IgorPomaranskiy: Thank you. But it seems using transactions as Gocht suggested seems more reasonable. (If it isn't please let me know why).

Comment: I don't think so (I've never try in that way), because as its name says, signals are executed before (`pre_save`) and after (`post_save`). But I've did what I recommed in my last comment. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks. I think overriding save method is good enough. Would you mind submitting your solution as an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the Submission's `save` method, call `UserResult` `update` method. And mark Submission's `save` method as `@transaction.atomic`. Then if an error happen while updating UserResult, Submission won't be saved.