# Django transactions: managing two different transactions atomically inside the overriding of save() method

Tags: python, django, transactions

In Django 1.4 I have a code like the following:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # model definition

    @transaction.commit_manually
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            do_other_things()
        except:
            transaction.rollback()
            raise
        else:
            transaction.commit()
            obj2 = MySecondModel(mymodel = self, foo = "bar")
            obj2.save()


class MySecondModel(models.Model):
    myModelId = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
    # other fields defining this model
```

As you can see, after creating an object of `MyModel` class, I have to create also another object of `MySecondModel` class, that has a reference to the first one.

In the code above, if something went wrong during `obj2.save()`, there would be no way to rollback the first transaction.

How can I handle those two transactions as a unique atomic transaction?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/30516268/3945375) can help

Comment: I cannot use `@transaction.atomic` in Django 1.4

Comment: Previously there was [commit_on_success](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/topics/db/transactions/#django.db.transaction.commit_on_success). Is it helpful?

Comment: Can you tell which database do you use?

Comment: Yes Gocht, it is. So the solution is decorate my save() with @commit_on_success (without transaction rollback/commit). Right?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Gocht in the comments under the question, a solution in Django 1.4 is using `@transaction.commit_on_success()`. The code could be something like this:

```
from django.db import models
from django.db import transaction

class MyModel(models.Model):
    # model definition

    @transaction.commit_on_success()
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        try:
            super(MyModel, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
            do_other_things()
            obj2 = MySecondModel(mymodel = self, foo = "bar")
            obj2.save()
        except:
            print 'exception'
            raise
        else:
            print 'job done'



class MySecondModel(models.Model):
    myModelId = models.ForeignKey(MyModel)
    # other fields defining this model
```